# как найти елементы по классу в обьекте

Tags: javascript

как можно найти елементы по классу используя обьекты, проблема с этим кодом что он не находим елементы которые мы задаем в var rect = new Rectangle("elem", 100, 100, "red"); - elem
html:

```
<div class="elem"></div>
<div class="elem"></div>
<div class="elem"></div>
<div class="elem"></div>
<div class="elem"></div>
<button class="action">action</button>
```

css:

```
.elem {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.elem.active {
    background: red;
}
```

js:

```
function ready() {

    function Rectangle(elem, w, h, c) {
        this.elem = elem;
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.color = c;
    }

    Rectangle.prototype.elemClass = function() {
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll(this.elem);
        for (let i = 0; elements.length > i; i++) {
            return elements[i];
        }
    }

    var rect = new Rectangle("elem", 100, 100, "red");

    document.querySelector(".action").onclick = function() {        
        rect.elemClass().style.background = rect.color;
    };

}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

Comment: вообще ничего не понятно, опишите какого результата вы хотите добиться

Comment: чтобы по клику все елементы имели background = red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не получиться это сделать таким способом, даже просто по той причине, что elemClass вернёт только последний элемент.

Может вот это поможет.

```
function ready() {

function Rectangle(elem, w, h, c) {
    this.elem = elem;
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
    this.color = c;
}

Rectangle.prototype.elemClass = function() {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(this.elem);
    return elements;
}

var rect = new Rectangle("elem", 100, 100, "red");

document.querySelector(".action").onclick = function() {
     var collection = rect.elemClass();
     for(let i; i < collection.length; i++) {
           collection[i].style.backgroundColor = rect.color;
     }
};

}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(this.elem);` ничего не вернет, так-как `var rect = new Rectangle("elem", 100, 100, "red");` селектор `elem` будет искать тэги

Comment: Он будет искать в этом объекте, свойство elem, ничего другого не пройзойдет.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю что именно вы хотели сделать в своем коде, но чтобы банально сменить елементам бэкграунд, надо просто достать их селектором, пробежаться по ним и поменять нужное свойтсво каждому елементу.

Вот, по клику все имеют `background = red` :

```js
function ready() {
  function Rectangle(elem, w, h, c) {
    this.elem = elem;
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
    this.color = c;
  }

  var rect = new Rectangle(".elem", 100, 100, "red");

  document.querySelector(".action").onclick = function() {
    document.querySelectorAll(rect.elem).forEach(function(el) {
      el.style.background = rect.color;
    });
  };
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

```css
.elem {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.elem.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="elem"></div>
<div class="elem"></div>
<div class="elem"></div>
<div class="elem"></div>
<div class="elem"></div>
<br />
<button class="action">action</button>
```

Comment: var rect = new Rectangle("elem", 100, 100, "red"); - мне нужно чтобы с этого места брался класс

Comment: @DimaVleskov поправил ответ, метод `elemClass` удалил, так как в упор не понимаю к чему он